# jquery not() and has() combined

Tags: jquery, list, html-lists

Im trying something like this:

```
$(".off-canvas-list li").not(has("ul")).addClass("liChildless");
```

This doesn't work though, how shall i write this code to add a class of "liChildless" to all li tags that doesn't have a child ul?

Comment: you missed wrapping `has("ul")` in quote and preceding it with a `:`. `.not(':has("ul")').addCla...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".off-canvas-list li:not(:has('ul'))").addClass("liChildless");
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/J64wu/)

Comment: This also worked and the code is more what I was expecting. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could to use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-functionindex):

```
$(".off-canvas-list li").filter(function () {
    return $(this).find("ul").length === 0;
}).addClass("liChildless");
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/63UuY/)

OTOH, I have just tested, you can combine [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selectors as well:

```
$(".off-canvas-list li:not(:has(ul))").addClass("liChildless");
```

[Check fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/DjVVR/)